# PAM unable to dlopen pam_sss.so pam_cap.so pam_systemd.so pam_pwquality.so

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, pam

Since yesterday i have a huge number of errors in journald log. New records appears at 3-5 in each second:

```
окт 24 09:08:37 ripcomp su[7405]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_sss.so): /lib/security/pam_sss.so: невозможно открыть разделяемый объектный файл: Нет такого файла или каталога
окт 24 09:08:37 ripcomp su[7405]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_sss.so
окт 24 09:08:37 ripcomp su[7405]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_cap.so): /lib/security/pam_cap.so: невозможно открыть разделяемый объектный файл: Нет такого файла или каталога
окт 24 09:08:37 ripcomp su[7405]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_cap.so
окт 24 09:08:37 ripcomp su[7405]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_systemd.so): /lib/security/pam_systemd.so: невозможно открыть разделяемый объектный файл: Нет такого файла или каталога
окт 24 09:08:37 ripcomp su[7405]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_systemd.so
окт 24 09:08:37 ripcomp su[7405]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_pwquality.so): /lib/security/pam_pwquality.so: невозможно открыть разделяемый объектный файл: Нет такого файла или каталога
окт 24 09:08:37 ripcomp su[7405]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_pwquality.so
окт 24 09:08:37 ripcomp su[7405]: No passwd entry for user 'riptor'
окт 24 09:08:37 ripcomp su[7405]: FAILED su for riptor by root
окт 24 09:08:37 ripcomp su[7405]: - ??? root:riptor
```

Logs in Russian, means "no such file or directory". On my system these files are in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security, not /lib/security.
I use Kubuntu 18.04 included in Windows AD domain via sssd. "riptor" is a domain account, included in local group "sudo". I don't have any troubles for logging on my system or using sudo. 
How to fix these error and find a source of their appearance? 
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was quiet easy. I found that the i386 packages were installed:

```
root@va-Q553:/etc# dpkg -l | grep pam
ii  libpam-cap:amd64                                  1:2.25-1.2                                      amd64        POSIX 1003.1e capabilities (PAM module)
ii  libpam-gnome-keyring:amd64                        3.28.0.2-1ubuntu1.18.04.1                       amd64        PAM module to unlock the GNOME keyring upon login
ii  libpam-modules:amd64                              1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2.18.04.1                        amd64        Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM
ii  libpam-modules:i386                               1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2.18.04.1                        i386         Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM
ii  libpam-modules-bin                                1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2.18.04.1                        amd64        Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM - helper binaries
ii  libpam-pwquality:amd64                            1.4.0-2                                         amd64        PAM module to check password strength
ii  libpam-runtime                                    1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2.18.04.1                        all          Runtime support for the PAM library
ii  libpam-sss:amd64                                  1.16.1-1ubuntu1.5                               amd64        Pam module for the System Security Services Daemon
ii  libpam-systemd:amd64                              237-3ubuntu10.41                                amd64        system and service manager - PAM module
ii  libpam-systemd:i386                               237-3ubuntu10.41                                i386         system and service manager - PAM module
ii  libpam0g:amd64                                    1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2.18.04.1                        amd64        Pluggable Authentication Modules library
ii  libpam0g:i386                                     1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2.18.04.1                        i386         Pluggable Authentication Modules library
ii  thunderbird                                       1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                amd64        Email, RSS and newsgroup client with integrated spam filter
```

I removed them:

```
apt remove libpam0g:i386
```

Unfortunately, it triggered the removal of openssh, so I reinstalled it back:

```
apt install openssh-server
```

Now everything is fine